# Tomcat not able to create temp folder when we delete it and restart tomcat

Tags: java

tomcat throws exception since it does not get path of temp folder.

I have tried to set environment variable in setenv.sh file but it not helped.
I am using CentOs 7.
Any leads will be appriciated.

[image: Tomcat not able to create temp folder when we delete it and restart tomcat]

Here i have attached the image of the exeption shown in the console.

```
 WARNING [http-nio-8300-exec-2] org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.createMimeConfig Cannot create temporary files. Multipart attachments will be limited to "4,096" bytes.
        java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
                at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
                at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2063)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.createMimeConfig(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:119)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderClientSide.<init>(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:101)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.MultiPartReaderServerSide.<init>(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:57)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
                at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
                at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
                at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.lambda$getAllServiceHolders$0(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:136)
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
                at java.util.LinkedList$LLSpliterator.forEachRemaining(LinkedList.java:1235)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
                at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
                at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
                at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:140)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getAllServiceHolders(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHolders(Providers.java:307)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:151)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.initialize(MessageBodyFactory.java:219)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory$MessageBodyWorkersConfigurator.postInit(MessageBodyFactory.java:114)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$2(ApplicationHandler.java:353)
                at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:3880)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:353)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:297)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:296)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:261)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
                at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:347)
                at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1164)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1117)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:788)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: :- Can you manually create temp folder within apache directory and verify once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jersey Client creation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589379/jersey-client-creation-error)

Comment: @Anand Diwedi--- yes i can create it manually but its not a fisible solution.

Comment: Don't delete the `temp` folder